# YII2. Change db connection by routing

Tags: database, yii2, prefix

I need to change db connection (prefix) by routing,
When user route to site.com/db1/post system used db1 components config, and when route to site.com/db2/post system used db2

```
'components' => [
'db1' => [
     ...,
    'tablePrefix' => 'base1_',
],
 'db2' => [
     ...,
     'tablePrefix' => 'base2_',
],
...
```

Can it`s possible?
Maybe have better solution to change db prefix.
I need to use one model with different table (only prefix change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options.  Probably the easiest is using url rules; see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules

```
rules => [
    '<db:db\d>/post' => 'site/post',
]
```

This will redirect db1/post to site/post with the "db" parameter set to "db1".  Then in your SiteController:

```
public function actionPost($db) {
    YourModel::setDb(Yii::$app->$db);
    $model = new YourModel();
    // do what you need with your model
    // and return the rendered result
}
```

In your model class, you will need to override the getDb() static method, and write a setDb method:

```
private static $_db;

public static function getDb() {
    if (isset(self::$_db)) {
        return self::$_db;
    }
    return ActiveRecord::getDb();
}

public static function setDb($db) {
    self::$_db = $db;
}
```

Comment: Thanks fot answer!
I forgot that i have too many controllers. 
I use another way by change User and for every User make yours db connection.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is similar at the advanced  template  .. where you have two different application with different config section .. in

```
/db1/config/main.php
```

you can place the db component  setted for accessing to the table prefix you prefer  (or also to database you prefer)

```
'components' => [
  'db' => [
 ...,
     'tablePrefix' => 'base1_',
  ],
```

and in

```
  /db2/config/main.php  

'components' => [
  'db' => [
 ...,
     'tablePrefix' => 'base2_',
  ],
```

You can use the common namespace for all the common application elemnts you need .. models, controllers ,views and so.. on
and each reseved namespace for specific elements..

Obviuosly this isjust a suggestion .. could be there are others  easy and smart solutions

*PS: using two separated database you don't need  different prefix..*